# how to remove through axle on raleigh 2.0?

Tags: maintenance

I have a [Raleigh RX 2.0 cross bike](http://www.raleighusa.com/bikes-open-road-cyclocross-rx-2-0) with through axles and I'm having trouble removing one. On the rear wheel, when i try to unscrew it, the lever unscrews but not the axle. If I keep unscrewing, the lever will eventually come off. I've tried taking it off and putting a back on a bunch of times but nothings happened. Any input would be greatly appreciated!! Also its a very new bike, and is cleaned after every ride (just had the wheel off yesterday)

Comment: Can you please add a photo or two, and which bike you actually have. I suspect the [RX 2.0](http://www.raleighusa.com/bikes-open-road-cyclocross-rx-2-0)? You may find the unrelated [Fox suspension fork instructions](http://www.ridefox.com/fox_tech_center/owners_manuals/010/eng/Content/Forks/32MM/InstructionsQR32mm.html) useful as they cover generic 15mm through axle assembly.

Comment: Thanks for the info. yes, its the RX 2.0. I just realized my race isnt until the afternoon tomorrow so ill have time to bring it by the shop before. I'll post here what the problem was in case anyone has a similar issue. Its a strange one

Comment: That would only be helpful if you also described your problem better, because currently I'm not sure what's actually wrong. That's where a photo would help a lot.

Comment: so turns out I had over tightened the axle, which was fairy easy (for a bike mechanic) to fix. the link you sent above actually did address the issue

Comment: I have the exact same issue on my rear thru axle on my Raleigh. The above link describes a cut out that you need to line up the quick release with in order to unscrew the thru axle. Mine has no such cutout. The quick release simple unscrews itself when you turn it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you have through axles front and rear, most likely 15mm (the Raleigh site is unclear).

The sequence for installing the wheels is shown on this [Fox front fork page](http://www.ridefox.com/fox_tech_center/owners_manuals/010/eng/Content/Forks/32MM/InstructionsQR32mm.html):

[image]

[image]

[image]

If you're screwing the QR lever around the axle you're almost certainly unscrewing something you shouldn't. Try closing the lever to the locked position, screwing it tighter, then when you meet resistance open it, screw another half turn, then close it. You should find it takes a little pressure to close, but still locks the wheel in place.

The animation and detailed instructions on the Fox site might help.

Comment: This answer is how to install and screw tight a through axle. The question was about how to remove it.